# If $I = \langle X^2,Y^2\rangle$ and $J=\langle XY\rangle$ are ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$, then what is their intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

We are given two ideals $I = \langle X^2,Y^2 \rangle$ and $J=\langle XY \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$. Clearly $I\cap J$ is the ideal generated by $XY^2$ and  $Y^2X$, which can be proven using Grobner bases. The first step in the proof is to define a new variable $W$ with some fixed lexicographic ordering and consider the new ideal $\langle WX^2,WY^2,(1-W)XY \rangle$, then the intersection of a Grobner basis with $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ gives the desired result.

My question is why we need to define this new variable, and why some elements in the original ideal are multiplied by $W$, but others by $(1-W)$. This first step in the proof seems not so obvious to me.

Comment: We don't *need* to. We do it because it works.

Comment: Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I,J\subset R$ ideals and $W$ an indeterminate over $R$. Then $[WI+(1-W)J]\cap R=I\cap J$. This should clarify your doubts, since $W(a-b)=0$ implies $a=b$ and if $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ we get they are in the intersection.

Comment: Avi Steiner: It's WHY it works that I am still a little confused about.

Comment: If your question is why such proof works then, I believe the above comment by @user26857 answers your question completely even without referring to Groebner basis. If your question is why do we need to use such proof, I think it is a more philosophical question to ask. In your particular question, a property of monomial ideals will give you one of the shortest ways to the conclusion.